# Какие индексы можно сделать или что изменить в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, индексы

Есть запрос

```
select count(*) 
   from table advert
   where    advert.n_category IN ( 92 )  and  advert.hide='show' and advert.moder='view' and on_delete='off' and blocked!='yes' and end_putdate>1622154297  and advert.country_adv =  3159  ;



n_category,end_putdate,country_adv  - int
hide,moder,on_delete,blocked - enum
```

**n_category** - id категории (в данном случае на сайте одна категория )

**end_putdate** - дата окончания объявления

**country_adv** - страна объявления

**hide** - скрыто,видно

**moder** - модерировано,не модерировано

**on_delete** - удалено, не удалено

**blocked** - блокировани, не блок..

Данный запрос выполняется примерно 3сек, 500 тыс записей. Как его можно оптимизировать путем добавления индексов  ? Возможно лучше переделать таблицу ?
Таблица MyISAM

Comment: Запрос не полный? Что за вторая скобка после IN ()?

Comment: поправил. Ошибка

Comment: Вам составной индекс самое то, если не меняется кол-во колонок в поиске

Comment: составной на все поля из запроса или какие-то определенные ? У меня был составной на поля enum , но результата это не дало